# How can a text file be automated converted like this using tools in linux?

Tags: linux, text

I have a text file with several lines.

I want to do the following:
1. Remove the first 14 characters. Leave the next 8 characters. Then delete everything on the line after that.

Then the file looks something like this.

```
20050013
AC040020
AC050024
```

1. At the beginning of each line, I want to add something like RAM[n] = 'h, where n keeps incrementing. I also want to add a ; at the end.

Then the file looks like this

```
RAM[0] = 'h20050013;
RAM[1] = 'hAC040020;
RAM[2] = 'hAC050024;
```

There has to be 10 entries in the file. So I add remaining entries and set them to 0. The file ends up like this:

```
RAM[0] = 'h20050013;
RAM[1] = 'hAC040020;
RAM[2] = 'hAC050024;
RAM[3] = 'h00000000;
RAM[4] = 'h00000000;
RAM[5] = 'h00000000;
RAM[6] = 'h00000000;
RAM[7] = 'h00000000;
RAM[8] = 'h00000000;
RAM[9] = 'h00000000;
```

I guess I could use a perl script or vi. How can this process be automated?

Comment: How can you get 3 lines of 4 (hexadecimal, i assume) characters by only keeping 8 characters ? your explanations are very confusing.

Comment: In the beginning each line has 8 hex characters.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read [`man sed`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed)?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try doing it using `awk` ? awk has a lot of features but its a little tough to write as code the thing that you are exactly trying to do.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/awk-introduction-tutorial-7-awk-print-examples/

You can check this link for possible examples...

Answer (score 1):

Use Awk.

```
{
    printf("RAM[%d] = '%s;\n", NR - 1, $0)
}
```

(Put that in `foo.awk`, then run `awk -f foo.awk` on your data.)

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to do with AWK. Use substring and $NR